# I can't open terminal on ubuntu 16.04 after python3 installation

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, terminal

I have a big problem; I tried to install python 3 on ubuntu 16.04 but after installation my terminal does't open anymore.
And then I try to remove python but the problem is still here. I opened xterm and i tried to launch gnome-terminal but I have this error:

```
"bash: /usr/bin/gnome-terminal: /usr/bin/python3 :FIle o directory does't exist"
```

I think there is some problem with different version of python on my pc but I can't find a solution.
Someone can help me ?
thanks

Comment: What version of python you Install ?

Comment: I install python 3.6

Comment: go into  /usr/bin and remove rm python3 and run ln -s python3.6 python3

Comment: use xterm  terminal and run command sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3

Comment: If you are installing using `apt-get update && apt-get install python3.6 -y` then the binary is `/usr/bin/python3.6`. To avoid calling `python3.6` you can run `alias python=python3.6` or use the symlink @GovindParashar suggested

Comment: Thanks to all, now it runs again :)

Answer (score 2):

I face the same problem after I tried to remove python 2 using terminal. I came up with a unusual solution.
Go to any folder on desktop.
Right click and select "Open in Terminal"
Terminal will be opened.
To go to home directory, type cd and hit enter.

This is just a temporary solution. If this doesn't works, its better to install the Ubuntu again.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following steps to sort the issue out:

```
sudo apt install dconf-cli
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/terminal
sudo apt-get remove gnome-terminal
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
sudo locale-gen --purge
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
reboot
```